# Why $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ is equivalent to $r = \cos(t)$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Repeating the question

> Why $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ is equivalent to the function $r = \cos(t)$ in polar coordinates?

The author's solution was

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't quite get "a bit" of algebra he is talking about.

So far what I did was

$$\begin{align}(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 + y^2  = \frac{1}{4} &\implies x^2 - x + \frac{1}{4} +y^2 = \frac{1}{4} \\ 
&\implies x^2 - x+y^2 = 0 \\
& \implies \cos (\theta)^2 r^2 - \cos (\theta) r + \sin^2 (\theta) r^2 =0 \\
& \implies r^2 -  \cos \theta r = 0
\end{align}$$

The only possibility (that I see) to obtain the desired result is to divide both sides by $r$ and rearrange. But in this case we need to suppose that $r ≠ 0$. Are we allowed to? And why in his solution he switched variable $\theta$ with $t$?

Comment: $r \neq 0$ because $r=0$ will refer to a circle with radius $0$ which definitely is not the case here. $t$ instead of $\theta$ is just a typo.

Comment: @AnuragA:  but the point $r=0$ satisfies the original equation.  It is one point on the circle.  In the polar formulation, it corresponds to $\theta=\frac \pi 2$

Comment: @RossMillikan The fact $r(r-\cos \theta )=0$ implies either $r=0$ (for all $\theta$) or $r=\cos \theta$ (for all $\theta$) or both. So I am referring to the case $r=0$ for all $\theta$ being a trivial circle. However the common point between the two circles will be captured by the equation $r=\cos \theta$ as well when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Perhaps I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last you can go to $r(r-cos \theta)=0$.  You can observe that $r=0$ corresponds to $x=0,y=0$ and is a solution for the original equation.  Then you can say that you are going to look for other solutions, where $r \neq 0$, so you can divide by it and get $r=\cos \theta.$  I don't know why the author switched to $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to express$C=\{(x,y)\big|(x-1/2)^2+y^2=1/4\}$  in polar coordinates. As you said, making $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ gives you $C=\{(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)|r(r-\cos t)=0\}$. As you pointed out, there is the chance for $r=0$, but this case corresponds only to the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$. 
So, we technically have
$$C=\{(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)\big|(r-\cos t)=0\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$$
i.e. 
$$C=\{(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)\big|r=\cos t\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$$
but note that the point $(0,0)$ is already considered when $r=0=\cos (\frac{\pi}{2})$. SO, this point is "redundant". We conclude 
$$C=\{(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)\big|r=\cos t\}$$
So, the curve is given by the equation $r=\cos t$ in polar coordinates.